# Need to Find specific messages in Inbox, save attachment to share, then move email to different folder VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, outlook, visual-studio-2017, console-application, move

I can connect to the outlook account, I can find my message(s), I can save the attachment to share, just can't figure out how to move to a different folder once the attachment is saved. Once all is working, email details to look for and account details will be passed from a SQL table and loop to process through them.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Diagnostics.Tracing
Imports System.Net.Mail

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim outlookApp As New Outlook.Application()

    Dim outlookSession As Outlook.NameSpace = outlookApp.Session
    outlookSession.Logon("UserID", "password", True, True)
    Console.WriteLine(outlookSession.CurrentUser)

Dim inboxFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder = outlookSession.GetDefaultFolder (Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox)
    Dim Subfolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder 'Tried it also just like the  inbox folder no difference
Subfolder = inboxFolder.Folders("Move to folder name")' Errors here operation failed, object could not be found


    Dim inboxItems As Outlook.Items = inboxFolder.Items
    For Each outlookItem As Object In inboxItems
        Dim mailItem As Outlook._MailItem = TryCast(outlookItem, Outlook._MailItem)
        If mailItem IsNot Nothing Then
            'Console.WriteLine(mailItem.Subject)
            If mailItem.SenderEmailAddress = "Reporting@successfactors.com" Then
                Dim attachments As Outlook.Attachments = mailItem.Attachments
                For Each attachment As Outlook.Attachment In attachments
                    'Just to test
                    Console.WriteLine("From " & mailItem.SenderEmailAddress)
                    Console.WriteLine("Subject " & mailItem.Subject)
                    Console.WriteLine("Attachment  " & attachment.FileName)
                    Console.WriteLine(inboxFolder.Items)
                    'Attachment does get saved
                    attachment.SaveAsFile("\\fileshare\folder\" & attachment.FileName)



                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachment)
                Next attachment
                mailItem.Move(Subfolder) 'doesn't move
                'Subfolder = GetObject.Folders("DailyDataFeed1")
                'mailItem.Move(DestFldr:=Subfolder)
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachments)
            End If




        End If

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookItem)
    Next outlookItem

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inboxItems)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(inboxFolder)
    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(outlookSession)
End Sub
```

End Module

I expect processed messages will be moved to a subfolder

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts and Inboxes?

Comment: No, a single account, one inbox on the Exchange server, I have multiple data files, but the folder I'm trying to move to is a subfolder on the exchange server.

Comment: Does the subfolder actually exist under the Inbox? Can you get it by its index number instead of by name?

Comment: Not sure how to get the index, novice at VB.net. My employer is locking down MACRO/VBA so having to figure out a different way.